# Are EC2 Windows instances charged per hour or per second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am appearing for AWS CCP tomorrow , I thought Windows EC2 instances are billed per hour but this confused me. Can anyone help me understand the difference between Windows Ec2 instance and Windows based Ec2 instance is the question wrong

[image: Exam question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another link would be the official documentation for the [on-demand EC2 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) stating:

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the
> time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each
> partial instance-hour consumed will be billed per-second for Linux,
> Windows, Windows with SQL Enterprise, Windows with SQL Standard, and
> Windows with SQL Web Instances, and as a full hour for all other
> instance types.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon EC2 instances running Windows were historically charged per hour.

However, they are now charged per-second.

As written in your screenshot: "Windows based EC2 instances **used to** follow pay-per-hour pricing earlier."

See: [Understand Amazon EC2 instance-hours billing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-hour-billing/)

Comment: ah okay thank you so much for the response. I missed the used to part.